# $ E( |X| ) = 0 $ implies $X = 0$ except possibly on a null set

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be random variable defined on a countable probability space. Suppose $E( |X| ) = 0$, then $X = 0 $ except possible on a null set.

We know $$ 0 = E ( |X| ) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |k| P(X = k) $$

So, if $k \neq 0 $, then $P(X = k) $ must be zero. But I am stuck here how can I show $X = 0 $ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and set $A_\varepsilon = (|X| > \varepsilon)$. Then $P(A_\varepsilon) \le \varepsilon^{-1}E(|X|) = 0$. Thus $P(A_\varepsilon) = 0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. Now if $A := (X \neq 0)$, then $A = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty A_{1/n}$, and thus $P(A) \le \sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(A_{1/n}) = 0$. Thus $X = 0$ except possibly on the null set $A$.

Comment: But If $X \neq 0$, then either $X < 0$ or $X > 0 $, why you only consider $X > 0 $ ?

Comment: I did not. Look back at the definition of $A_\varepsilon$. Also, if $X \neq 0$, then $|X| > 0$ -- this is the key.

Comment: Got it! thanks a lot ( +1 ). One last question: Is it possible to conclude that $X = 0$ everywhere ?

Comment: Not without more conditions.

Comment: IS there a counterexample ?

Comment: I should have been clearer. It's not impossible that $X = 0$ everywhere, but rather it can be possible that $X$ is not identically zero. For example, consider the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and let $X$ be the indicator function on $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$. Then $E(|X|) = 0$, but $X$ is not identically zero.

Comment: Another example: Consider the measure $\delta_0$ on $\{0,1\}$ ($\delta_0$ is the Dirac mass concentrated at $0$). Let $X$ be the indicator function on $\{1\}$. Then $E(|X|) = E(X) = X(0) = 0$, but $X$ is not identically zero. This example is more relevant since you assumed the sample space is countable.

Comment: Note that for this theorem, you can remove the countability assumption for the sample space.